# How to Disable MSI in Magento 2.4.6-p1

Tags: magento2, msi-source

I have tried the below way to disable MSI, but it is showing below error when I view any sales order.

> Error: Cannot instantiate interface
> Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\GetStockItemConfigurationInterface
> in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50

Here is a warning when trying to apply `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command

```
Warning: Undefined array key "inventory_source" in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php on line 354
```

> php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory
> Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi
> Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales
> Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi
> Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct
> Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer
> Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi
> Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport
> Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification
> Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi
> Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi
> Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations
> Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache
> Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi
> Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping
> Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection
> Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi
> Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi
> Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock
> Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
> Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout
> Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection
> Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryGraphQl
> Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport
> Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickup
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi
> Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension
> Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi
> Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi
> Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi
> Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser Magento_InventoryWishlist

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

> php bin/magento cache:flush

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Inventory --clear-static-content

php bin/magento module:disable Magento_InventoryAdminUi --clear-static-content

php bin/magento module:disable Magento_InventoryApi --clear-static-content
```

Run Upgrade, Flush Cache, and Reindex:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Clean Generated Files:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
```

Deploy Static Content:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

**Run the below command After that Run Upgrade, Flush Cache, and Reindex:**

```
php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickup Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser Magento_InventoryWishlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two best options to disable the MSI modules:

**Solution1:**

Add all the MSI modules (you want to disable) packages to the `composer.json` replace section. for example:

```
"replace": {
    "magento/module-inventory": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-admin-ui": "*"
 }
```

**Solution2:**

You can require the below composer package. This will also automatically remove all the MSI modules.

```
composer require yireo/magento2-replace-inventory
```

These are the best options because the above approach do not allow MSI modules to be installed. So these packages will be excluded.